# Formatear fecha GMT Madrid PHP

Tags: php

Al ingresar la variable para obtener la fecha, me estoy fijando en el log que me la deja dos hroas antes de la actual en España.

```
$nowtimename = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
```

Y necesito que sea la que usamos ahora mismo en España, no tener que esta pensnaod que siempre esta dos hroas atrasados, supongo que añadiendole una variable que le sume dos podria bastar, pero por si existe alguna forma de hacerlo en el `gmdate`mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el manual online de PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) con la función `gmdate()` no puedes cambiar la zona horaria:

> Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is
>   Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Con la función `date()` se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$nowtimename = date('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
echo $nowtimename;
```

Edito mi respuesta porque revisando un poco más a fondo he visto que se puede hacer lo siguiente si necesitas hacerlo con la función `gmdate()`:

```
$timezone  = 1;  // Madrid: GTM + 1
echo gmdate("Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
```

Personalmente, prefiero la primera opción pero dependerá de tus necesidades.

Comment: Perfecto la segunda solución, pero en vez de por `3600`es por `7200`por las diferencia shorarias, muchisimas gracias.

Comment: El parámetro "I" de la función date() es para indicar que tenga en cuenta el horario de verano, pero no me ha dado tiempo a probarlo a fondo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que especificar tu zona horaria antes de generar la fecha.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

Comment: Hola Maria, bienvenida a [es.so]. Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio y [answer] para hacer mejores respuestas :D Un saludo